# When satisfation of SFINAE condition depends on the function being declared, is that condition guaranteed to be false?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Consider this code:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct A {};

struct B
{
    template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_constructible_v<B, T &&>, std::nullptr_t> = nullptr>
    B(T &&) {}
};

int main()
{
    B b(A{});
}
```

Both Clang, GCC, and MSVC [accept it](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:12,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:12,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:12,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:12),source:%27%23include+%3Ctype_traits%3E%0A%0Astruct+A+%7B%7D%3B%0A%0Astruct+B%0A%7B%0A++++template+%3Ctypename+T,+std::enable_if_t%3C!!std::is_constructible_v%3CB,+T+%26%26%3E,+std::nullptr_t%3E+%3D+nullptr%3E%0A++++B(T+%26%26)+%7B%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++B+b(A%7B%7D)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:conformance,i:(compilers:!((compilerId:gsnapshot,options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B23+-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic-errors%27),(compilerId:clang_trunk,options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B23+-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic-errors%27),(compilerId:vcpp_v19_latest_x64,options:%27/std:c%2B%2Blatest%27)),editorid:1,langId:c%2B%2B,libs:!()),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Conformance+Viewer+(Editor+%231)+3/15%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4).

Is this code valid, or should the compilers reject it?

Interestingly, if I use `requires` instead of `enable_if_t`, GCC and Clang start [rejecting it](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:48,endLineNumber:8,positionColumn:5,positionLineNumber:8,selectionStartColumn:48,selectionStartLineNumber:8,startColumn:5,startLineNumber:8),source:%27%23include+%3Ctype_traits%3E%0A%0Astruct+A+%7B%7D%3B%0A%0Astruct+B%0A%7B%0A++++template+%3Ctypename+T%3E%0A++++requires(!!std::is_constructible_v%3CB,+T+%26%26%3E)%0A++++B(T+%26%26)+%7B%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++B+b(A%7B%7D)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:conformance,i:(compilers:!((compilerId:gsnapshot,options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B23+-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic-errors%27),(compilerId:clang_trunk,options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B23+-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic-errors%27),(compilerId:vcpp_v19_latest_x64,options:%27/std:c%2B%2Blatest%27)),editorid:1,langId:c%2B%2B,libs:!()),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Conformance+Viewer+(Editor+%231)+3/15%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4), while MSVC still accepts. The error boils down to `satisfaction of constraint depends on itself`.

But shouldn't the same thing cause an error in the first code? Or is this undefined?

```
#include <type_traits>

struct A {};

struct B
{
    template <typename T>
    requires(!std::is_constructible_v<B, T &&>)
    B(T &&) {}
};

int main()
{
    B b(A{});
}
```

Comment: I suspect you run foul of [[temp.point\]p7](https://wg21.link/temp.point#7.sentence-4). If you replace the template with the built-in `__is_constructible` (which is evaluated every time and not cached like templates), you run into an infinite template instantiation loop: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/13o1ojafd

Comment: somewhat related https://stackoverflow.com/q/73308975/4117728

Comment: somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70874679/7325599

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`is_constructible_v<T...>` is an `inline constexpr bool`.

`B b(A{});` does an overload resolution to pick a viable constructor.

When checking if `template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_constructible_v<B, T &&>, std::nullptr_t> = nullptr> B(T &&)` is viable, `std::is_constructible_v<B, T &&>` is evaluated, where `T` is deduced as `A`.

To evaluate `std::is_constructible_v<B, A &&>`, the variable template is instantiated and it's initializer is evaluated. Overload resolution is done again for `B t(declval<A&&>());` ([[meta.unary.prop]p9](https://wg21.link/meta.unary.prop#9)).

This again tries the same constructor template and has to check for the value of `std::is_constructible_v<B, A &&>`. However, this refers to the *same* variable `std::is_constructible_v<B, A &&>` from beforehand. Since the initialization isn't finished, the variable is not in its lifetime ([[basic.life]p(1.2)](https://wg21.link/basic.life#1.2)), so reading it is not a constant expression, so `std::is_constructible_v<B, A &&>` isn't a constant expression in this case. This is a SFINAE-able error, so the constructor isn't viable.

This means that the original `std::is_constructible_v<B, A &&>` is now initialized to `false`, making your original constructor viable.

A similar thing happens if you have `std::is_constructible<B, T &&>::value`, except `std::is_constructible<B, A &&>` is an incomplete type the second time around and `::value` is the SFINAE error.

---

I think this is still IF-NDR. The second overload resolution depends on the value of `std::is_constructible_v<B, A &&>`, which would have a different result depending on where it is evaluated (`true` or `false` instead of "not yet in lifetime"). And [[temp.point]p7](https://wg21.link/temp.point#7.sentence-4):

> If two different points of instantiation give a template specialization different meanings according to the one-definition rule, the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

Though I could not find how points of instantiation are defined for variable templates (or the initializer for a variable template).

Comment: If your interpretation (before the horizontal line) is correct, this is quite similar to how stateful metaprogramming works.

Comment: @WeijunZhou Yep, so we could come up with a valid way to do that using stateful metaprogramming.