# Overload operator<< for non printable iterables with concepts

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, variadic-templates, c++-concepts

I would like to overload `operator<<` for "stuff that looks like a container that don't already have it" (I'm going to explain what I mean a bit later), constraining the accepted type with concepts, that is

- the overload isn't going to be there for `std::thread`, because it "doesn't look like a container"
- the overload isn't going to be there for `std::string`, because it "looks like a container" but already has an overload
- the overload is going to be there for `std::vector` because "it looks like a container" and it doesn't already has an overload

An example that is "unconstrained" :

```
#include <iostream>

template<template<class, class ...> class Container, class T, class ... OtherParams>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Container<T, OtherParams...>& c)
{
    for(const T& t : c)
        out << t << " ";
    return out;   
}

int main()
{        
    vector<char> v = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
    cout << v << endl;

    //string s = "Hello";
    //cout << s << endl; //ambiguous between the above overload, and that of std::string
}
```

I *really* want to use the above template syntax (because I really need the type `T` in my "real" problem) to characterise "stuff that looks like a container".

I can write a concept for "stuff not already having operator<<" :

```
template<class T>
concept NotPrintableConcept = ! requires(std::ostream& out, const T& t)
{
    { out << t };
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << NotPrintableConcept<std::vector<char>> << std::endl; //true
}
```

My objective is to combine the two above syntaxes into *a single* overload of `operator<<`. However, I'm not able to

1. write the above `requires` expression "inline", that is, write a template function constraining its `T` to types not having an overload for `operator<<` without declaring an actual concept;
2. combine the "inline requires expression" with the above overload of `operator<<` so that I can print "stuff looking like a container that I can't already print"

Point 2 is problematic with concepts : because while the declaration of the concept `NotPrintableConcept` is valid, I cannot write an operator<< in the following way

```
template<NotPrintableConcept Container>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Container& c)
{
    for(const auto& t : c)
        out << t << " ";
    return out;   
}
```

because then we make the constraint depend on itself: as soon as I have an instantiation of the operator, further calls will fail. On top of that, the above syntax doesn't include the "complete detail" about the Container type (it is a template of some T and other stuff I'l not interested in).

Somehow, this above tryout behaves differently (that is, wrong) than if I use "good 'ol enable_if SFINAE expressions". Below, a complete example working with `std::enable_if` :

```
template<class> struct sfinae_true : std::true_type {};
template<class ToPrint> static auto check_print(int) -> sfinae_true<decltype(std::cout << std::declval<ToPrint>())>;
template<class ToPrint> static auto check_print(long) -> std::false_type;
template<class ToPrint> struct is_printable : decltype(check_print<ToPrint>(0)) {};
    
template<class ToPrint> using NotPrintable = std::enable_if_t<! is_printable<ToPrint>::value>;

template<template<class, class ...> class Container, class T, class ... Whatever, NotPrintable<Container<T, Whatever...>>* = nullptr>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Container<T, Whatever...>& c) 
{ 
    for(const T& t : c)
        out << t << " ";
    return out;
}

int main()
{        
    std::vector<char> v = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};        
    std::cout << v << std::endl; //ok

    std::string s = "Hello";
    std::cout << s << std::endl; 
}
```

My question is then : is there any way to make the above syntax elegant with concepts?

Comment: I don't think this is possible in a legal way (because the test for `<<` is self-referential). You need to manually opt-out each individual type that you don't want to count as a range, you can't rely on it already having `<<`. But I wouldn't bother with this at all, `std::format` can print ranges out of the box (or `fmt::format` from libfmt, if your standard library doesn't support that yet).

Comment: Also I wouldn't force the container to be a template (`Container<T, OtherParams...>`), it's better to test it with something like `std::ranges::input_range`.

Comment: I understand your suggestions: but like I said, my real is not really related to iterables or `<<`. It could just be the same question for `operator+` . Also, the above mwe uses `Container<T, OtherParams...>` because that's what I need in my problem.

Comment: The concept idea has the problem that as soon as you add the "missing" operator, it is no longer missing. This is similar to the "Set of all sets not containing itself", the [Russel paradox](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/russell-paradox/)

Comment: *"my real is not really related to iterables or `<<`"* This doesn't change my answer, this is still illegal. See e.g. this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77621528/2752075

Comment: Ok. I understand that, in this case, concepts cannot "elegantly solve" SFINAE constraints and enable_if expressions. I edited my above question in this sense, while providing a working solution with enable_if. The question is why does it work with enable_if, and not with concepts ? And, can I make it work ?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77320573/c-generic-overload-of-operator-for-stl-containers-produces-ambiguous-overloa